# could anybody give me an example on how to insert hyperlink in a customized dialog

Tags: wix

I tried the following code, but it is not work. could anybody give me some example? thanks.

```
<Control Id="URL2" Type="Hyperlink" X="20" Y="105" Width="320" Height="18">
          <Text><![CDATA[<a href="http://info.yahoo.com/privacy/us/yahoo/messenger/details.html/">Joy of Setup</a>]]></Text>
        </Control>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hyperlink control type [was added in Windows Installer 5.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd407936.aspx). Hence, for the previous versions it will fail. See [this article](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/articles/careful-with-that-hyperlink-on-your-msi-dialog/index.htm) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this. But a possible workaround is to have a button in your custom dialog call a custom action that could launch the URL in a browser. You could set the text of the button as the URL and then pass that to the custom action as a parameter so the custom action would be reusable. It is not exactly what you are looking - it is more of a workaround.